# Not getting client IP correctly for first time

Tags: c, sockets

I not getting the correct client IP address for first time. This is my server main code.

**server.c**:

```
int  main()
{
    int sockfd, connfd, lisfd, retval;

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, clntaddr;
    socklen_t client;
    struct packet pckt;
    int clnt_len;
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
            perror("socket");
            exit(1);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(8000);
    retval = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    if(retval) {
            perror("bind");
    }

    if((lisfd = listen(sockfd, 4)) < 0) {
            perror("listen");
            exit(3);
    }
    clnt_len = sizeof(clnt_len)-1; // clnt_len = sizeof(clnt_len);
    while(1) {
            if((connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clntaddr, &clnt_len)) < 0) {
                    perror("accept");
                    exit(2);
            }
            printf("IP address is: %s\n", inet_ntoa(clntaddr.sin_addr));

            read(connfd, &pckt, sizeof(pckt));
            printf("%s\n", pckt.msg);

    }
```

}

`packet` is a structure declared in `hdr.h` like below.

```
struct packet {
    char msg[50];
    int cmd;
};
```

The **output** is:

```
IP address is: 255.127.0.0
Hi
IP address is: 127.0.0.1
Hello
IP address is: 127.0.0.1
Good
...
```

For first time, I'm getting the wrong IP. I don't understand what is going on? How to get correct IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [accept(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) man page, `clnt_len` should be initialized to the available size in the `clntaddr` *before* calling `accept()`:

```
 while(1) {
     clnt_len = sizeof clntaddr;
     if ((connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clntaddr, &clnt_len)) < 0) {
         perror("accept");
         exit(2);
     }
```

Edited: `clnt_len = sizeof(clnt_len)-1; // clnt_len = sizeof(clnt_len);` is the problematic line. It sets `clnt_len` to an invalid value: one less than the length of the socket length variable, when it should be the amount of memory available in `clntaddr`.

This is less than `sizeof (struct sockaddr_in)`, and therefore `clntaddr` will not be assigned when `accept()` returns with the first connection. `clnt_len` does get assigned to the length of the client address (and yes, it is allowed to be larger than its original value; that just means the `clntaddr` wasn't large enough; see the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) for details), and therefore on the following connections, `clnt_len` is the proper size, and you get the address for the second and further connections, only missing the initial connection address.

To fix, add the `clnt_len = sizeof clntaddr;` line to the beginning of the `while (1)` lopp body.

Questions?

Comment: How can you imagine clnt_len is not initialized? If clnt_len is 0, then I will get "bad address" error.

Comment: @SGG: I'm not a telepath! Your code does not initialize it. If your actual code differs, please fix the code in your question appropriately. As to `clnt_len`, I was wrong; it is most likely between 1 and `sizeof (struct sockaddr_in)-1` during the first invocation -- that explains exactly the symptoms you are seeing. Fixed my answer, thanks.

Comment: @SGG and this answer *still applies*. Your updated code now reads: `clnt_len = sizeof(clnt_len)-1` which sets the wrong size (the size of an `int` less one octet. It should be the size of the *structure*, and should be *inside* the loop as shown in this answer).